# Re-positioning captions in lightbox2

Tags: javascript, css, positioning, lightbox, caption

I'm a total noob and I've successfully downloaded lightbox2 and am wondering if there is a way to move the caption to the right of the image.

I have read some of the other tutorials describing how to find a line of code in the js file... but they are quite old and it looks like I may have a newer version.

I've been trying to play around with the css but to no avail.  I have no idea what to look for in the js. version of the file.  Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Most probably, you don't need to tinker with js at this point. The easiest way for us to help would be if you created a [mcve] (here, in the question, using the `<>` button), but it's probably too much to ask at this point.So... 1) please link the exact library you are using (there are a ton of lightbox plugins outthere). 2) If possible, provide a bit more context on your setup. Are you running this on a local server, is there a place on web where we can inspect what you have?

Answer (score 0):

Using your web browser's document inspector can be very helpful when tinkering with css.

If you override the `.lb-details` class you can position the text to the right.

```
.lb-data .lb-details {
    text-align: right;
}
```